# Snowflake Stored Procedure & UDF in JavaScript - Issue with JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Disclaimer: I'm new to JavaScript & new to writing JavaScript Stored Procedure in Snowflake.

I'm trying to create a Stored Procedure which will send an Email Alert Notification consisting of lists of Snowflake Tasks that has been failed in the last three hours.

When I attempt to execute the Procedure, I get the below error:

`JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in USP_TASKFAILURE_ALERT at 'var task_info = 'select name,state,scheduled_time,completed_time,error_code,error_message,database_name,schema_name from snowflake.account_usage.task_history where scheduled_time >= dateadd('hour',-3,current_timestamp())' position 191`

Stored Procedure Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS "SALESANALYSIS_DW"."SALES".USP_TASKFAILURE_ALERT()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var task_info = 'select name,state,scheduled_time,completed_time,error_code,error_message,database_name,schema_name from snowflake.account_usage.task_history where scheduled_time >= dateadd('hour',-3,current_timestamp())
and query_id is not null and state != 'SUCCEEDED' and cast(scheduled_time as date) = current_date() order by scheduled_time desc';

rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: task_info});

while (rs.next())
{
tsk_name = rs.getcolumnvalue(1);
tsk_state = rs.getcolumnvalue(2);
tsk_scheduletime = rs.getcolumnvalue(3);
tsk_completedtime = rs.getcolumnvalue(4);
tsk_error_code = rs.getcolumnvalue(5);
tsk_error_msg = rs.getcolumnvalue(6);
tsk_database_name = rs.getcolumnvalue(7);
tsk_schema_name = rs.getcolumnvalue(8);
var tsk_err_msg_parse = tsk_error_msg.replace(/'/g,'"');

var proc = 'call system$send_email('NOTIFICATION_INT','abhixyz@outlook.com','TASK FAILURE NOTIFICATION','Task Name '+ tsk_name +' is failed due to the error code '+ tsk_error_code +' and error message is '+ tsk_err_msg_parse + '' );'
var stmt = snowflake.createstatement({sqlText: proc});
var result = stmt.execute();
}

result = "Succeeded! Email Alert has been sent for the list of Failed Task";
return result;
$$;
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of misspellings in your code and therefore it is not syntactically correct as of now.

Here is the corrected code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_TASKFAILURE_ALERT()
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
var task_info = "select name,state,scheduled_time,completed_time,error_code,error_message,database_name,schema_name from snowflake.account_usage.task_history where scheduled_time >= dateadd('hour',-3,current_timestamp()) and query_id is not null and state != 'SUCCEEDED' and cast(scheduled_time as date) = current_date() order by scheduled_time desc";

rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: task_info});

while (rs.next())
{
tsk_name = rs.getColumnValue(1);
tsk_state = rs.getColumnValue(2);
tsk_scheduletime = rs.getColumnValue(3);
tsk_completedtime = rs.getColumnValue(4);
tsk_error_code = rs.getColumnValue(5);
tsk_error_msg = rs.getColumnValue(6);
tsk_database_name = rs.getColumnValue(7);
tsk_schema_name = rs.getColumnValue(8);
var tsk_err_msg_parse = tsk_error_msg.replace(/'/g,'"');

var proc = "call system$send_email('TASK FAILURE ALERT','abhixyz@outlook.com','TASK FAILURE NOTIFICATION','Task Name " + tsk_name + " is failed due to the error code " + tsk_error_code + " and error message is " + tsk_err_msg_parse + "')";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: proc});
var result = stmt.execute();
}

result = "Succeeded! Email Alert has been sent for the list of Failed Task";
return result;
$$;
```

Now, this code will still fail if your Integration name is not correct, as `TASK FAILURE ALERT` doesn't sounds like the right name for your integration (does your integration name really have white spaces in between?).

The corrections I've made:

- the SQL statement should be enclosed in `""` since you already are using `''` inside
- the `getcolumnvalue` is actually `getColumnValue`
- the `createstatement` is actually `createStatement`

Comment: Thanks bro . It is working now . I have replaces the notification integration with correct one and made the correction.